# Strict aliasing and union of char arrays

Tags: c++, c++14, strict-aliasing

I sort of expect what the answer will be already, but am curious what the standard says about this.

The setup: I want to control the exact offset of fields in a structure, and specify them directly in the field type. Here is the magic:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>

template <uint32_t OFFSET, typename T>
struct FieldOverlay
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<T>::value, "Can only be used with trivial types");

    FieldOverlay() = delete;
    FieldOverlay(FieldOverlay&& other) = delete;
    FieldOverlay(FieldOverlay const& other) = delete;

    FieldOverlay& operator = (T const& val) { new (buf + OFFSET) T(val); return *this; }

    operator T()
    {
        T v;
        ::memcpy(&v, buf + OFFSET, sizeof(T));
        return v;
    }
private:
    char buf[OFFSET + sizeof(T)];
};

// Precisely control member offsets
union MyMessage
{
    FieldOverlay<0, uint32_t> x;
    FieldOverlay<7, uint32_t> y;
};

void exampleUsage(MyMessage& m)
{
    m.y = m.x;
}

struct MyMessageEquivalent
{
    uint32_t x;
    char padding[3];
    uint32_t y;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
```

This compiles on gcc 6.3 with `-O3 -std=c++1z -fstrict-aliasing -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror` without any errors, and works as expected. (See godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/DHWLD9)

Question: Is this kosher according to the standard? I think it gets very dicey because there's not a single "active" member of the union `MyMessage`. However, since everything is accessed through `char` arrays could that help with the strict-aliasing rules?

Comment: "*However, since everything is accessed through char arrays*" I see a lot of casts, which shows that "everything" is very much not being accessed through `char` arrays.

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant that the ultimate storage for all these values is in `char` arrays.

Comment: Well, only one member of a union can be active at any one time.  If you violate that then it is UB.

Comment: Lines like `T& asT() { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(buf + OFFSET); }` are probably not valid as the memory at `buf + OFFSET` was not originally of type `T`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Pedantically speaking yes. Since this is C++, so it's UB. If it were C99, then it's IB since it explicitly allows union type-punning. But practically speaking, I'm not aware of any compilers that treat C and C++ differently. And all of them will apply the C99 rules and allow union type-punning.

Comment: @Mysticial I agree, but if you are want to use a compiler extension in a question then the question should include a link to the extension so we can all be informed.

Comment: @RichardCritten Let's assume `T` is trivial. (I added a `static_assert`)

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy deferring to Nicol Bolas

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy: "*Let's assume T is trivial*" Which would matter if the standard had an exception to its object lifetime rules on the basis of triviality. But it *doesn't*. So it's still UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has lots of problems, but you'll invoke UB *long* before strict aliasing is even an issue.

`MyMessage::x` and `MyMessage::y` are not layout compatible types. They also do not have a common initial sequence. Yes, despite the fact that they both store an array of `char`, they do not store the *same sized* array of `char`. Those two arrays are of different lengths, and there is nothing in the common initial sequence rules that say that two structs which contain two arrays of the same base type but of different sizes have a common initial sequence.

Therefore, you cannot attempt to access `x` while `y` is the active member of the union. And vice-versa.

And FYI: your reinterpret casts provoke UB as well. There is no `T` in that memory, and `reinterpret_cast` cannot *create* an object. So accessing that memory as though it contained a `T` violates the standard. Also, the standard doesn't allow you to access an object through a misaligned pointer.

So basically, what you're trying to do isn't going to ever work.

Comment: I have changed the code to avoid usages of `reinterpret_cast`. But I guess the union thing is still UB according to the standard. I wish there was a clause for unions of trivial types... Especially because in this case I never access the memory that is meant for other fields, so the "relevant" parts don't overlap.